# One line setting environment variable and execute command, got different results in sh and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to figure out, how the oneliner

```
var=value command
```

actually works in sh. I expect variable `var` to be passed to the environment of `command`, but shouldn't exist in the current environment (please, do not omit disclaimer at the end!) 
 
First, let's try it in bash

```
#bash
$ var=      #just to be sure it's empty
$ var=value echo something
. something
$ echo "$var"
.

$ var=value set something
$ echo "$var"
.
```

For now, it works as expected. But when we go to sh and retype the same input, it'll be like that:

```
#sh
$ var=
$ var=value echo something
. something
$ echo "$var"
.

$ var=value set something
$ echo "$var"
. value
```

And the last one differs. Is `set` command some kind of special case for sh? Why has the variable `var` been saved in our current environment?

disclaimer: I know that `echo` and `set` are shell built-in's and thus environment variables we pass them by `var=value command` are wasted, but my question is about the syntax only. I mean, they *should* have been wasted, but in sh, when typed `set`, the variable was somehow passed into the current environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set` is a "special" built-in, defined as such in the POSIX specification.

> As described in Simple Commands, variable assignments preceding the invocation of a special built-in utility remain in effect after the built-in completes; this shall not be the case with a regular built-in or other utility.

So in this case, `bash` is actually in violation of the POSIX specification. Running in POSIX mode, though, it behaves the same as `sh`:

```
$ bash --posix
$ var=value set something
$ echo $var
value
```

Comment: Excellent answer.   Just curious: can you think of any reason why this special-case behavior is a good idea?  The same result could be accomplished without a special case via `var=value; set something`.

Comment: I'm not really sure why they *must* affect the shell. I'll just note that the commands classified as special built-ins are required to be built-in, since they are commands that affect the shell, rather than just being optionally built-in for efficiency. As such, it wouldn't really make sense for assignments to be temporary, since there is never a separate command being run.